# How do I display a string in View in Swift from HKSampleQuery

Tags: swift, healthkit

since this is my first Swift project and I am new to programming in general. I need some help with extracting the sample data I fetched from the query and printing it in the console. I am looking for a way to extract latestHr from the local scope and display it in the View in the app itself which is in the scope below:

```
var body: some View {

    return VStack {

    }
```

but I couldn't find a way to do it correctly.
This is most of the code I am using and the parts for calculation and fetching.

```
    func latestheartRate(){
        guard let sampleType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate) else{return}
        let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: Date())
        
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: Date(), options: .strictEndDate)
        
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)
        
        
    
        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: predicate, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit), sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) {(sample, result, error) in guard error == nil else {
            return
        }
            let data = result![0] as! HKQuantitySample
            let unit = HKUnit(from:"count/min")
            let latestHr = data.quantity.doubleValue(for: unit)
            let date = DateFormatter()
            date.dateFormat = "HH:mm E, d MMM y"
            let StartDate = date.string(from: data.startDate)
            let EndDate = date.string(from: data.endDate)
            print("Latest Hr\(latestHr) BPM // StartDate \(StartDate): EndDate \(EndDate)")
            
            let HR = String(latestHr)
            
           
        }
        
        healthStore.execute(query)
        
        
        

    }
    
        
    //trigger the function to authorize read and write heart rate
    init()
    {
        authorizeHealthKit()

    }
    var body: some View {
        
        return VStack {
            
        }
```

Comment: As you see, your result is an array and you are using the first entry in that array. The last value will be the latest HR value, not as you wrote, the first entry.